# Rails: params in format.html { render ... }

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, templates

I'm trying to pass params in a controller method's `format.html` like this:

```
def create
  @doc = Doc.new(params[:doc])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @doc.save
      format.html { redirect_to share_url(@doc.user.ftp, @doc) }
    else
      format.html { render "new", :locals => { :template => @doc.template_id } }
    end
  end
end
```

I get a no method error which tells me that I'm sending the right parameter to `:template` in the local variables:

```
local_assigns {:template=>4}
```

Is there something I'm missing to get that to work? It should redirect to the `doc#new` action but it's going to the `doc#index` instead. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using this syntax within a controller:

```
render "new", :locals => { :template => @doc.template_id }
```

means that you're rendering the `new.html.erb` template, not a partial. You are unable to pass local variables along to a non-partial view. What you should be doing is calling `render "new"`, and referring to `@doc` in that view as you require it.